# Windows 11 sometimes crashing on boot when rebooting from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bsod, gentoo

When rebooting from Gentoo Linux into Windows 11 through GRUB (I used os-prober to find Windows Boot Manager) I get the BSOD "KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED" (Kernel failed to load). This happens at (what I think) random.

I use 2 different UEFI partitions for Linux and Windows bootloaders, and this seems to occur after mounting C:\ filesystem. I use an Acer Aspire A515-56. The address causing the BSOD seems to be `ntoskrnl.exe+415b00`. Here is my partition layout for the computer:

[Image of my partition layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eEIm.png)

I am currently unable to provide `fdisk -l` output, but I can provide it if required.

My computer uses an NVME drive, if that is relevant.

If I boot from GRUB, without being in Linux first, Windows does not crash. When Windows does crash, a force reboot fixes it (It does not reboot automatically). I have already disabled Fast Startup in BIOS and Windows, but the BSOD still shows up.

Gentoo boots just fine, without issue.
Windows also boots just fine from GRUB (secure boot disabled) unless I have first booted into Linux.

Hope to find an answer soon, and please note that I'm not always availiable to give further information (but I will gladly provide further information), and that this is my first question on StackExchange.

Secure boot is disabled, because I would not be able to boot into Gentoo Linux if I had it enabled. As far as I know, (and I don't know too much about UEFI) enabling it would end up making GRUB not work (and I kind of need it to boot into any OS, but I do have F12 boot selection enabled), and I don't think enabling it would fix my issue, because Secure boot only really checks if the OS to boot is signed, and if its valid, and it shouldn't affect OS operation (as far as I know). Secure boot is also disabled no matter if I go into Linux or Windows. So, I don't see how Secure boot may affect this issue.

Fast startup is already disabled.

The BSOD 1st parameter is a 0xC0000005: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

It crashes on both a reboot from Windows to Linux and back and a shutdown > boot into Linux > boot into Windows.

Comment: Do you have Secure Boot enabled or disabled?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled. I also edited my question to add that, thank you.

Comment: You are aware that Windows 11 technically requires Secure Boot, right?  There are plenty of Linux distributions that support Secure Boot.

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure boot support, but as far as I am aware it does not require Secure boot to be enabled. It works just fine with Secure boot disabled, and it only sometimes crashes when I reboot from Linux into Windows (or shut down Linux and start up and select Windows)

Comment: ALL evidence points to that the fix action, for KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, is to disable and then reenable Secure Boot. The fact it only happens after booting into Linux, and never from Windows into Windows, tells me it's linked to the fact Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: Hm. Never thought of that. What do you mean with "Disable and then reenable Secure Boot"? Do you mean that I need to do that every time I want to reboot into Windows?

Comment: It’s a reference that in order to solve this in a traditional sense, in existing questions to this error, accepted answers suggested disabling then enabling Secure Boot to be the solution.

Comment: Try to disable fast startup.

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't help much, and sometimes Windows still tries fast startup or hibernation.

Comment: Please see [Bug Check 0x1E: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x1e--kmode-exception-not-handled). Gentoo supports Secure Boot \[[here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Security_Handbook/Bootloader_security) and [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8652037.html)\]. Fast Boot should also be disabled in the BIOS/UEFI firmware if the option is available there, and if hibernation is disabled, Fast Boot should be impossible AFAIK since Fast Boot relies upon the `hiberfile.sys`. Why are you using two EFI partitions?

Comment: I'll check that. Fast boot is also disabled in UEFI firmware, but I use a laptop, and I realised hibernation is used if my battery is too low and my computer has to shut off, so I'd rather keep it enabled. I'm using 2 EFI partitions, because in the case I break something on Linux, I still have Windows unaffected. I never edit Windows' EFI partition.

Comment: If you need to keep hibernation enabled, then you need to make sure that you always use “Restart” from within Windows prior to switching to Linux. Are you doing this or are you booting into Linux after using Shutdown in Windows?

Comment: I don't remember if I use the Reboot function or if I start it from boot (through shutdown). I'll see if that's the issue, though.

Comment: I have tested this 3 times. Rebooting Windows and going into Linux and rebooting into Windows again seems to make it not BSOD. This might indeed be a hibernation issue. I have seen a method of Shift+Shutdown which forces the system to shut down without hibernation / fast startup. But I am looking for a solution which lets me boot straight into Linux without a BSOD from Windows later. Should I force disable hibernation, risking a corruption when battery is critical? (It never gets critical, actually but has gotten pretty close.)

Comment: I'm marking this question as answered, I'll re-open it if it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to fix it by fully disabling hibernation. This can be done by typing `powercfg.exe /h off` in a Administrator command prompt. I'll re-open this question if this problem comes up again.

Just as a warning: If you are on a laptop (like me), if you disable hibernation, if your battery level is critical and Windows shuts down, it won't save your OS state because hibernation is disabled.

Update: Seems it does not BSOD on reboot, but it still BSODs if I shut down first. `C:\hyberfil.sys` does not exist, so hibernation is disabled.

Comment: When you mount the Windows partition from Linux, doesn’t it warn you that it is dirty/currently mounted?

Comment: I don't mount the Windows partition from Linux. Also, it can't be dirty/currently mounted because Windows is not running when I'm loaded into Linux, and I have NTFS drivers in Linux. If it was dirty, Windows would do a chckdsk (checkdisk) operation on bootup.